# why jmeter counter is not working

Tags: jmeter, counter

My jmeter counter does not increments with below flow:-

> Thread Group ---->Loop Controller 2 times ---> Counter & Transaction
>   Controller (In the name of the transaction controller I am using
>   counter reference name)

When I run my script, I see both the loop prints the counter value 1.
Any Idea ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you have inside the `Transaction Controller`?  Do you reference the variable c in the name of the sample inside Transaction controller?

Comment: you have set maximum value to 2, is this ok ? Could you show a screenshot of your plan ?

Comment: The Reference Name c I have used in the name of Transaction Controller only. Transaction controller again consist of some sub samplers but reference name c is not used for those sub samplers

Comment: Add debug sampler under loop controller and verify what is the value of c in each iteration using View Results Tree. I simulated above scenario and getting c value incremented in each loop. verified in 2.13 and 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Put Counter under Transaction Controller

> Thread Group ---->Loop Controller 2 times ---> Transaction
>   Controller (In the name of the transaction controller I am using
>   counter reference name) --> Counter